# Java E-Shop project

Tags: java, object

So I have an exercise about creating a functional e-shop with a minimal CMD UI. I have certain instructions and rules to follow while creating this and that's what makes it so difficult for me.

So firstly I have to create a class ierarchy, at the top of which stands the general Product.class and then below that the sub-classes Motherboard, CPU, GPU etc. Each of these sub classes contain their respective constructors. However, in the description of my exercise it isn't stated which items are going to be avalaible for immediate sale or should be ordered. Thus, I think that I'm supposed to choose these randomly meaning that I will have to create each and every one of these 'objects' by calling their constructors, like Motherboard mb1 = new Motherboard(motherboard info). Is there another way of implementing this? Because it seems like it's not the best way.

Now for my problem, say I have the required objects created and through the UI and consecutive questions the user will choose what product to buy, how am I going to 'transfer' this chosen object to my Sale.class so I initiate the sale and go on with the program?( The sale class has to print the item's info which is stored in its object and then reduce the items quantity from the shop's reserve)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question is too broad - if this is homework you should just start and come back if you have a specific question.

Comment: I have started. I have already created the subclasses and their superclass but I don't know how to begin creating the sale class.

Answer (score 0):

Your sale class should have a reference to the listed items. This probably should be a List or a Set.

Comment: If I did it this way, does it mean that I will have to use like 50 if statements? Because we are talking about many avalaible products. It just doesnt seem right to have that much if statements to determine what product the user chose.

Comment: No, don't do 50 if statements! You probably can do a loop on a list of items by only referring to them as Product, and not as their specific class.